# Get ui-router's ui-view to repopulate default content?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I set default content for ui-router's ui-view without a template?

Right now I have something like this:

```
<div ui-view>
  Default Content
</div>
```

As the states change, the view updates as expected. The problem is if I want to go back to the "default" view:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

..the "Default Content" is no longer available. I understand that using a template would be the easiest solution but I need the default view to be indexable. Is there a way to accomplish this without templates or something like HTML snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a direct way to repopulate `ui-view` with default content, but I found a workaround that may help you: the idea is to save the content of the `ui-view` element at compile time to make *UI Router* to treat it as a regular template.

I wrote a directive, also named `uiView`, that saves the template and doesn't requires you to touch the html

```
app.directive('uiView', function($templateCache){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        compile:  function (element)
        {
            // Saves template with ui-view element content
            $templateCache.put('$index.html', element.html());
        }
    };
})
```

You also have to add a state to point to the saved template (`$index.html`), and mark it as the default state:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state("index",{
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '$index.html' // points to saved template
        })

        [...] // more states

    // Set `index` as default state
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
})
```